# Is there a simple valuation method for a spin-off

Tags: trading, spin-off

"Liberated Syndication" Libsybsyn.com is being spun off. This may be the first publicly traded podcast company. S-1 shows positive earnings and 30% revenue growth. Is there a simple method to estimate price when it starts trading in August. Thanks for any input.

Comment: No, there is no simple method. A company is worth what a company is worth, and after spinning off the sum of the two values may be lower or higher than the single company was worth.

Answer (score 1):

Every industry is going to have different metrics that are used for valuations in general.  Further, much of a spin-off's valuation is derived from its ability to be a profitable free-standing entity.

Another big factor in valuing a spin-off is its time in business.  Companies spinning off divisions with long track records will naturally expect (and receive) higher valuations than newer companies with less data on which to evaluate their viability.

The short answer is, you'd have to be more specific about the company (and industry) you're referring to in order to get more precise information.

I hope this helps.

Good luck!